# Chrome Extension Disappears while clicking outside of its resolution

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, extension-methods, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

Is there anyway that I can make Chrome Extension's window stick in window even while clicking outside of its resolution?

I'm trying to make it Sticky on the window for one simple google login so that I don't need to go back again to click extension to open it.

Comment: No, but you can inject the UI as a DOM element (even an iframe via web_accesible_resources) or open a separate window.

Answer (score 0):

By using [tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/) you could retrieve `windowId` of the window you want to focus on. You could do it only if needed e.g. by using `query` method from that API. You could pass `url` for example.

If you created a window that you want to be still focused then you have its id already in the hand.

After that, you could use [window API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-update) `update` method in order to draw attention or focus. Take a look at `updateInfo` params - `focus` and `drawAttention`.

The same could be done by using `tabs` API. You could pass `tabId` and the URL you want to redirect someone.

Now in order to make it work you have a couple of options:

1. You can use `setInterval` which would be used to check if the tabId and `windowId` you want are active and focus the window/tab you want in another case.
2. Because in the MV3 extensions using `setInterval` is not recommended you could use [alarms](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/alarms/#type-AlarmCreateInfo). Please take a look at `AlarmCreateInfo`, `when` param should help you instead of triggering the alarm periodically.
3. You could also use event listeners from both `windows` and `tabs` API to listen on tab / window focus change. Then you will be able block the change (from user perspective) by methods I described before.

You should play with all approaches and pick on that suits you, because all of them have some drawback. But don't want to make that comment very long.